# ¿Cómo cambiar la presentación Slider ul li y reemplazarlos por un div?

Tags: jquery, html, html5, css, css3

Anteriormente ya publique una pregunta del mismo tema @Alvaro Montoro me ayudo a crear una barra de progreso.

Ahora en el mismo código quiero sustituir los elementos `ul` y `li` que corresponden a la presentación del **Slider** Quiero remplazarlos por un `Div`.

> **Ejemplo:** El contenedor del **Slider** de [Este sitio web](http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/). Si pueden observar la presentación del Slider es por medio de un `Div` tanto las imagenes por medio de un `background-image` como el cuerpo del contenido.

A pesar de que tengo el mismo diseño el mismo efecto. Quiero remplazar los elementos **ul** y **li** por un **Div** que todo el contenido correspondan en la presentación por medio de un `Div`.

Para ende así no mostrar las imagenes por medio de `<img src="">`. Si no crear un **background-image** en cada **Div**.

**Ejemplo** el Slider de [Este sitio web](http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/).

Código completo:

```js
$(function() {
  var SliderModule = (function() {
    var pb = {};
    pb.el = $('#slider');
    pb.items = {
      panel: pb.el.find('li')
    }

    // Variables Necesarias
    var SliderInterval,
        currentSlider = 0,
        nextSlider = 1,
        lengthSlider = pb.items.panel.length;

    // Initialize
    pb.init = function(settings) {
      this.settings = settings || {duration: 8000} 
      var output = '';

      // Activamos nuestro slider
      SliderInit();

      for(var i = 0; i < lengthSlider; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          output += '<li class="active"></li>'; 
        } else {
          output += '<li></li>';
        }
      }

      // Controles del Slider
      $('#slider-controls').html(output).on('click', 'li', function (e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (currentSlider !== $this.index()) {
          changePanel($this.index());
        };
      });
    }

    var SliderInit = function() {
      //SliderInterval = setInterval(pb.startSlider, pb.settings.duration);
      $("#barra").animate({
          width:"100%"
        }, 
        pb.settings.duration,
        "linear",
        pb.startSlider
      );                     
    }

    pb.startSlider = function() {
      $("#barra").css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls li');

      if (nextSlider >= lengthSlider) {
        nextSlider = 0;
        currentSlider = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      // Efectos
      controls.removeClass('active').eq(nextSlider).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');

      // Actualizamos nuestros datos
      currentSlider = nextSlider;
      nextSlider += 1; 
      SliderInit();
    }

    // Funcion para controles del slider
    var changePanel = function(id) {
      //clearInterval(SliderInterval);
      $("#barra").stop().css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls li');

      // Comprobamos el ID
      if (id >= lengthSlider) {
        id = 0;
      } else if (id < 0) {
        id = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      // Efectos
      controls.removeClass('active').eq(id).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(id).fadeIn('slow');

      // Actualizamos nuestros datos
      currentSlider = id;
      nextSlider = id+1;

      // Reactivamos el slider
      SliderInit();
    }


    return pb;
  }());
  SliderModule.init({duration: 4000});
});
```

```css
/*!
 * @Design slider
 */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
 
ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.slider-container{
  width:779px;
  height:448px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
  height: 360px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-wrapper li {
  display: none;
}

li.slide-current {
  display: block;
}

.slider-wrapper li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-controls {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -125px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.slider-controls li {
  background: #415066;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-controls li.active {
  background: #00c5b9; 
} 

#barra {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:15px;
  height:10px;
  background:#00c5b9;
  width:0%;
  z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide"><!-- Root slide -->
  <div class="slider-container"><!-- Root slider container -->
    <ul id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">
      <li class="slide-current">
        <img src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="slider-controls" class="slider-controls"></ul>
    <div id="barra"></div>
  </div><!-- End slider container -->
</div><!-- End slide -->
```

Espero haber sido claro, trate de cambiar los elementos **ul** y **li** pero no logre que funcionara, me ayudan a remplanzar los elementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edición

He cambiado los `ul` y `li` de todo tu código, entonces tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```js
$(function() {
  var SliderModule = (function() {
    var pb = {};
    pb.el = $('#slider > div');
    pb.items = {
      panel: pb.el
    }

    // Variables Necesarias
    var SliderInterval,
        currentSlider = 0,
        nextSlider = 1,
        lengthSlider = pb.items.panel.length;

    // Initialize
    pb.init = function(settings) {
      this.settings = settings || {duration: 8000} 
      var output = '';

      // Activamos nuestro slider
      SliderInit();

      for(var i = 0; i < lengthSlider; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          output += '<div class="active"></div>'; 
        } else {
          output += '<div></div>';
        }
      }

      // Controles del Slider
      $('#slider-controls').html(output).on('click', 'div', function (e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (currentSlider !== $this.index()) {
          changePanel($this.index());
        };
      });
    }

    var SliderInit = function() {
      //SliderInterval = setInterval(pb.startSlider, pb.settings.duration);
      $("#barra").animate({
          width:"100%"
        }, 
        pb.settings.duration,
        "linear",
        pb.startSlider
      );                     
    }

    pb.startSlider = function() {
      $("#barra").css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls div');

      if (nextSlider >= lengthSlider) {
        nextSlider = 0;
        currentSlider = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      // Efectos
      controls.removeClass('active').eq(nextSlider).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');

      // Actualizamos nuestros datos
      currentSlider = nextSlider;
      nextSlider += 1; 
      SliderInit();
    }

    // Funcion para controles del slider
    var changePanel = function(id) {
      //clearInterval(SliderInterval);
      $("#barra").stop().css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls div');

      // Comprobamos el ID
      if (id >= lengthSlider) {
        id = 0;
      } else if (id < 0) {
        id = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      // Efectos
      controls.removeClass('active').eq(id).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(id).fadeIn('slow');

      // Actualizamos nuestros datos
      currentSlider = id;
      nextSlider = id+1;

      // Reactivamos el slider
      SliderInit();
    }


    return pb;
  }());
  SliderModule.init({duration: 4000});
});
```

```css
/*!
 * @Design slider
 */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
 
div .item {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.slider-container{
  width:779px;
  height:448px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
  height: 360px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-wrapper > div {
  display: none;
}

div.slide-current {
  display: block;
}

.slider-wrapper div .item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-controls {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -125px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.slider-controls div {
  background: #415066;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-controls div.active {
  background: #00c5b9; 
} 

#barra {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:15px;
  height:10px;
  background:#00c5b9;
  width:0%;
  z-index:99;
} 

.item{
  height: 268px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide"><!-- Root slide -->
  <div class="slider-container"><!-- Root slider container -->
    <div id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slide-current">
        <div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg1.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div><div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg2.jpg');"></div></div>
        <div><div class="item" style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg3.jpg');"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-controls" class="slider-controls"></div>
    <div id="barra"></div>
  </div><!-- End slider container -->
</div><!-- End slide -->
```

---

Este `slider` esta hecho con **Bootstrap** lo cual el diseño es completamente diferente a lo que ya cuentas, pero sin embargo se hace el uso de `div` que es lo que necesitas

> Uno de los principales problemas al cargar una imagen por `url("...")` es que hay un `delay` y para mostrar la imagen puede tardar demasiado e incluso puede alterar el comportamiento de la animación de la barra de tiempo

Te dejo el [ejemplo del carrusel(`slider`) de bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) adaptado a tu necesidad:

```js
//eperar a que carge la imagen para comenzar la animacion
$('.item div').ready(function(){
    animar();
})
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
    interval: 4000,
    pause: null
  })
  $('.carousel-indicators').find('li').on('click',function(){
    $("#barra").stop().css("width", 0);
    animar();
  });

function iniciar(){
  $("#barra").css({"width": 0})
  animar();
}

function animar(){
  $("#barra").animate(
    {
      width:"100%"
    }, 
    4000,
    "linear",
    function(){iniciar()}
  );
}
```

```css
#barra {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:15px;
  height:10px;
  background:#00c5b9;
  width:0%;
  z-index:99;
}
.item div{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg1.jpg');  "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <div style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg2.jpg');  "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <div style="background-image: url('http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg3.jpg');  "></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="barra"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por dedicar el tiempo en responder, es un ejemplo que quizás lo tomare a futuro algún día. No me gusta trabajar con librerías **Bootstrap** ni utilizar ningún tipo de **plugin**. Un +1 quizás el ejemplo le ayude a otros usuarios amantes de las librerías **Bootstrap**. Saludos :)

Comment: @J.Doe he editado mi respuesta con tu código no puse las imagenes en los div ya que antes de cambiar la siguiente imagen se muestra debajo de la actual, y perdona por el `slider` de `Bootstrap` no había visto las etiquetas hasta que publique la respuesta

Comment: no te preocupes, gracias por la respuesta. Amigo la idea de remplazar los elementos **ul** y **li** por un **div**. Era para mostrar las imágenes mediante **background-image**  `<div class="item"  style="background-image: url(http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg2.jpg);"></div>` para luego crearle un estilo  `{
  height: 558px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
} ` [Ejemplo este slider](http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/) eh realizado los cambios similar pero no me muestra las imágenes??? Me ayudas.

Comment: @J.Doe por eso te comente _no puse las imágenes en el `div` porque al momento de cambiar se colocan de bajo de la actual_ e incluso intente cambiando el nombre de la etiqueta `img` a `div` y colocando un aproximado del `div` que comentas y lo que hace el `javascript` es detectar 6 `divs` de los cuales 3 se colocan blancos intentando llegar a la solucion estube haciendo cambios en el `JS` y llegue a mostrar 3 pero la 3ra imagen nunca se veía y la 2da la tomaba como la 3ra, lo cual la segunda era un `div` blanco

Comment: entonces amigo, el interés es realizar lo comentado, pero no es valido. Tendré que postear una nueva pregunta al parecer si no se soluciona.

Comment: @J.Doe he resuelto el problema de las imágenes espero no genere inconvenientes en el `JavaScript` lo he modificado un poco, únicamente el inicio

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo dado a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Pues es tan sencillo como reemplazar los `ul` y los `li` por `div` y que retoques los estilos para que se comporten como quieres. Para que te sea más fácil referenciarlos y no tengas conflictos a la hora de darle estilos ponle un nombre de clase.

No me he parado mucho a editar el código así que es posible que tenga algún fallo.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var SliderModule = (function() {
    var pb = {};
    pb.el = $('#slider');
    pb.items = {
      panel: pb.el.find('div.nombre-de-clase')
    }

    // Variables Necesarias
    var SliderInterval,
        currentSlider = 0,
        nextSlider = 1,
        lengthSlider = pb.items.panel.length;

    // Initialize
    pb.init = function(settings) {
      this.settings = settings || {duration: 8000} 
      var output = '';

      // Activamos nuestro slider
      SliderInit();

      for(var i = 0; i < lengthSlider; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          output += '<div class="active"></div>'; 
        } else {
          output += '<div class="nombre-de-clase"></div>';
        }
      }

      // Controles del Slider
      $('#slider-controls').html(output).on('click', 'div.nombre-de-clase', function (e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (currentSlider !== $this.index()) {
          changePanel($this.index());
        };
      });
    }

    var SliderInit = function() {
      //SliderInterval = setInterval(pb.startSlider, pb.settings.duration);
      $("#barra").animate({
          width:"100%"
        }, 
        pb.settings.duration,
        "linear",
        pb.startSlider
      );                     
    }

    pb.startSlider = function() {
      $("#barra").css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls div.nombre-de-clase');

      if (nextSlider >= lengthSlider) {
        nextSlider = 0;
        currentSlider = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      // Efectos
      controls.removeClass('active').eq(nextSlider).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');

      // Actualizamos nuestros datos
      currentSlider = nextSlider;
      nextSlider += 1; 
      SliderInit();
    }

    // Funcion para controles del slider
    var changePanel = function(id) {
      //clearInterval(SliderInterval);
      $("#barra").stop().css("width", 0);
      var panels = pb.items.panel,
          controls = $('#slider-controls div.nombre-de-clase');

      // Comprobamos el ID
      if (id >= lengthSlider) {
        id = 0;
      } else if (id < 0) {
        id = lengthSlider-1;
      }

      // Efectos
      controls.removeClass('active').eq(id).addClass('active');
      panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
      panels.eq(id).fadeIn('slow');

      // Actualizamos nuestros datos
      currentSlider = id;
      nextSlider = id+1;

      // Reactivamos el slider
      SliderInit();
    }


    return pb;
  }());
  SliderModule.init({duration: 4000});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide"><!-- Root slide -->
  <div class="slider-container"><!-- Root slider container -->
    <div id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="nombre-de-clase slide-current"><img src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="nombre-de-clase"><img src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="nombre-de-clase"><img src="http://themeinthebox.com/demo/color/images/slider/bg3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="slider-controls" class="slider-controls"></ul>
    <div id="barra"></div>
  </div><!-- End slider container -->
</div><!-- End slide -->
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slider-container{
  width:779px;
  height:448px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
  height: 360px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-wrapper .nombre-de-clase {
  display: none;
}

.nombre-de-clase.slide-current {
  display: block;
}

.slider-wrapper .nombre-de-clase img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-controls {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -125px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.slider-controls li {
  background: #415066;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-controls .nombre-de-clase.active {
  background: #00c5b9;  
} 

#barra {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:15px;
  height:10px;
  background:#00c5b9;
  width:0%;
  z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: A pesar de que no le tomaste mucho tiempo en editar el código funciona correctamente solo un pequeño detalle es que no aparecen los botones, sera que puedes observar el motivo el porque no aparecen y si no es mucho pedir adaptarlos como en el antiguo **Slider** Saludos :)

Comment: puedes realizar las practicas y ejecución del código aquí [https://jsfiddle.net/zc8vd6vn/](https://jsfiddle.net/zc8vd6vn/)

Comment: @J.Doe revisando el jsFiddle estoy viendo que dentro del `ul` no hay nada. Por lo que entiendo viendo el código deberías tener un par de `li` a modo de controles. ¿Puedes actualizar el código?